# Marks not showing in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to draw a simple line with some markings at designated points, the code I always use to draw something like this doesn't seem to work and I don't know why. In particular, what I obtain is the line with no markings on it.
I would be grateful of any help, the code is the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis line style={draw=none},
        ticks=none,
        xmin=-5.5,
        xmax=5.5,
        ymax=-5,
        ymin=5,
        anchor=origin
    ]
        \addplot[]coordinates{(-5,0)(5,0)};
        \addplot[dotted]coordinates{(-5.5,0)(-5,0)};
        \addplot[dotted]coordinates{(5.5,0)(5,0)};

        \foreach \k in {-4,-1,...,4}{
            \addplot[mark=diamond*]coordinates{(\k,0)};
        }
        
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Try `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{-4,-1,...,4}{
            \addplot[mark=diamond*]coordinates{(#1,0)};
        }`.

Comment: You need to switch the values for `ymin` and `ymax`. The value for `ymin` should be lower than that for `ymax`.

Comment: @user23623 `\foreach` should work here, because it is not inside an `\addplot` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you correct the values for `ymin` and `ymax` so that the value for `ymin` is lower than that for `ymax`, the marks will show.

But you might want to change the value list of the `\foreach` loop. If you say `{-4,-1,...,4}`, this will result in the list `{-4, -1, 2}`. Why? Well, with the first number, you set the starting value for the loop list, which is -4. With the second number you set the second value and the step size, that is, the second value being -4 and the step size being 3. With the number after the three dots, you set the last value of the value list, 4. But with your first two numbers being -4 and -1 and (therefore) the step size being 3, 4 will never be reached and, thus, the loop will stop at 2 as the next value, 6, is already larger than the value you defined as last value.

In the following example, I changed the loop list to a step size of 1:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis line style={draw=none},
        ticks=none,
        xmin=-5.5,
        xmax=5.5,
        ymin=-5,
        ymax=5,
        anchor=origin
    ]
        \addplot[]coordinates{(-5,0)(5,0)};
        \addplot[dotted]coordinates{(-5.5,0)(-5,0)};
        \addplot[dotted]coordinates{(5.5,0)(5,0)};

        \foreach \k in {-4,-3,...,4} {
            \addplot[mark=diamond*]coordinates{(\k,0)};
        }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I think the reason for the marks not showing in your example is that the marks are clipped away, as you create a domain that goes in the negative direction.